# Two canvas above each others return different x,y coordination

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I draw 2 canvas above each other,in bottom I loaded an image.
I'm using the top canvas for mouse move events and draw some info according to the image loaded on the bottom canvas (for example, when mouse above eyes, I draw circle).
The problem is that eventhough both canvas has the same width & height, the coordination of x,y of the top canvas seems not fit the bottom one, do I missing anything?
I tried to set the top canvas.scale as the one bellow after loaded the image.
Thanks!
JB

Comment: Each canvas has it's own coordinate system starting in the top left corner. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: You need to subtract the offset of the canvas from the mouse position to get local canvas position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subtract the current mouse position from the canvas position like this

```
let x = e.clientX - canvasA.offsetLeft
let y = e.clientY - canvasA.offsetTop
```

Doing this will give you the canvas' local position instead of the window's position.

Here is an example (Move your mouse over the red canvas):

```js
const canvasA = document.getElementById('a')
const canvasB = document.getElementById('b')

let ctxB = canvasB.getContext('2d')

canvasA.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  ctxB.clearRect(0, 0, canvasB.width, canvasB.height)

  // Get the local x/y coordinates of the mouse on the red canvas
  let x = e.clientX - canvasA.offsetLeft
  let y = e.clientY - canvasA.offsetTop

  // Mimic the position on the blue canvas with a white dot
  ctxB.beginPath();
  ctxB.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctxB.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctxB.fill();
})
```

```css
#a {
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
<canvas id="b"></canvas>
```

Here is what happens if you don't calculate this, I added padding to the top of the body, as you see the dot is now `50px` lower than the mouse.

```js
const canvasA = document.getElementById('a')
const canvasB = document.getElementById('b')

let ctxB = canvasB.getContext('2d')

canvasA.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  ctxB.clearRect(0, 0, canvasB.width, canvasB.height)

  // Get the local x/y coordinates of the mouse on the red canvas
  let x = e.clientX
  let y = e.clientY

  // Mimic the position on the blue canvas with a white dot
  ctxB.beginPath();
  ctxB.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctxB.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctxB.fill();
})
```

```css
body {padding-top: 50px;}

#a {
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
<canvas id="b"></canvas>
```

If scrolling needs to be taken into account, you can use `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

```
let x = (e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft) - canvasA.offsetLeft
let y = (e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop) - canvasA.offsetTop
```

```js
const canvasA = document.getElementById('a')
const canvasB = document.getElementById('b')

let ctxB = canvasB.getContext('2d')

canvasA.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  ctxB.clearRect(0, 0, canvasB.width, canvasB.height)

  // Get the local x/y coordinates of the mouse on the red canvas
  let x = (e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft) - canvasA.offsetLeft
  let y = (e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop) - canvasA.offsetTop

  // Mimic the position on the blue canvas with a white dot
  ctxB.beginPath();
  ctxB.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctxB.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctxB.fill();
})
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 150vh;
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
<canvas id="b"></canvas>
```

Comment: clientX - offsetLeft unfortunately doesn't take scrolling into account => your example snippet is broken on my small screen.

Comment: @Kaiido I have updated the answer to add scrolling into account.